# IS NULL check on column not executing

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, oracle10g

I have the following trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test 
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON table_cust 
  FOR EACH row 
BEGIN
   IF(:NEW.visibility_flag='True') THEN
      --Do something
   END IF;      

   IF(:NEW.visibility_flag is null) THEN
      --do something
   END IF;
END test;
```

Every time I check the IS NULL condition my trigger does not execute. If the null check is removed then it executes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there any value of VISIBILITY_FLAG that _is_ actually NULL?

Comment: Compilation errors?  Is trigger valid after adding block with `is null` check?

Comment: yes the values in the column visibilty_flag are set to null and there are no compilation errors after adding the block with is null check

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "trigger does not execute"? What is the error message? Does it compile but not fire?

Comment: it compiles, but the query writtern inside the visibilty_flag is null block doesnt execute.This means the trigger is not fired

Comment: How do you know it doesn't fire?  What code does `do something` obscure?

Comment: i know its not firing because the queries return inside the blocks or even outside dont update the columns i want them to. THis means the trigger is not fired or if it is then my queries arent gettign executed

Answer (score 0):

I think that is you remove the  "is null" part, then you'll have only IF(:NEW.visibility_flag) -> which in terms is like the upper one (if (expression = 'True') - with the example below you can see that only one of the IF statements will be entered:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test 
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON table_cust 
  FOR EACH row 
BEGIN
   IF(:NEW.visibility_flag='True') THEN
      --Do something
   ELSE IF(NVL(:NEW.visibility_flag, '0') = '0') THEN
      --do something
   END IF;
END test;
```

Comment: Are you confusing `='True'` with a boolean test? `IF(:NEW.visibility_flag)` isn't valid because Oracle SQL doesn't have a boolean type, and that statement implies `visibility_flag` is a boolean column.

Comment: I guess the True string is used as a pseudo boolean flag.

Comment: No the column is not a boolean, it contains string values.I am pretty sure it will not consider the column as boolean

Comment: I even tried the above approach, doesnt seemed to work. I have no clue why

Comment: If the field `visibility_flag` of the `table table_cust` contains the string "True" then the first IF statement is entered, if the newly inserted field is NULL, then the second. You seem to be having different data which is entered?